# Am I making a multi-label dataset right?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to make a tf2.0 dataset which contains images already in np.array format and 7 different labels which for each image.
And my code is `dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data,labelZh,labelCh1,labelCh2,labelCh3,labelCh4,labelCh5,labelCh6))`

---

Am I using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slice`correctly?
Cause when I fit the dataset into my network I get an error:
`TypeError: in converted code: TypeError: map_fn() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 8 were given`

Follow is my network:

```
def Forward():
input=keras.Input(shape=(64,64,3),name='title')
x=layers.Conv2D(8,3,activation="relu",padding='same',kernel_initializer="he_normal")(input)
x=layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x=layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x=layers.Conv2D(16,3,activation="relu",padding='same',kernel_initializer="he_normal")(x)
x=layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x=layers.Conv2D(32,3,activation="relu",padding='same',kernel_initializer="he_normal")(x)
x=layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x=layers.Conv2D(64,3,activation="relu",padding='same',kernel_initializer="he_normal")(x)
x=layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x=layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
output_Zh=layers.Dense(32)(x)
output_1=layers.Dense(34)(x)
output_2=layers.Dense(34)(x)
output_3=layers.Dense(34)(x)
output_4=layers.Dense(34)(x)
output_5=layers.Dense(34)(x)
output_6=layers.Dense(34)(x)
model=keras.Model(inputs=input,outputs=[output_Zh,output_1,output_2,output_3,output_4,output_5,output_6])

return model
```

Comment: You have 7 outputs with 34 components (32 for the first one), wouldn't it be one output with 7 components in your case?

Comment: Cause I'm doing a multi-label multi-class classification,and I got 7 different classes so I created 7 outputs....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test the code right now, but does this solve your problem:

```
dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    data,
    {
        'output_Zh': labelZh,
        'output_1': labelCh1,
        'output_2': labelCh2,
        'output_3': labelCh3,
        'output_4': labelCh4,
        'output_5': labelCh5,
        'output_6': labelCh6
    }
))
```